# Cannot set wkhtmltopdf margins (top and bottom)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf 0.10.0 rc2 on Ubuntu (Linux 3.2.0-24-generic #38-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux). The problem I'm experiencing is that I can't create PDFs with margin-top or margin-bottom. I'm not getting any errors.

I'm using the following commands:

```
wkhtmltopdf -T 50 -B 50 http://google.com ./test.pdf
wkhtmltopdf --margin-top 50 --margin-bottom 50 page.html ./test.pdf
```

However, when I try the following, margin-left and margin-right works perfectly (but still no margin-top or margin-bottom)

```
wkhtmltopdf -L 50 -R 50 -T 50 -B 50 page.html ./test.pdf
```

It doesn't matter which URL or page I try to convert. How can I set a margin-top and margin-bottom?

Answer (score 14):

I believe you're missing units. Try:

```
wkhtmltopdf -L 50mm -R 50mm -T 50mm -B 50mm page.html ./test.pdf
```

mm, of course, is millimeters. You could also do 0.5in or 2cm, something like that.

Comment: "mm" & "cm" units work, but "in" units appear to be ignored.  (I'm using 0.12.1-rc for Win64.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm super late here, but I ran into a similar issue (I kept changing the margins to no effect) and after a lot of work I figured out my issue: My ***content*** was of a limited size, so the margins didn't matter.

I was using Bootstrap 3 to create a layout for my PDF, and in Bootstrap I had a `<div class="container">` element wrapping the whole page. Containers in Bootstrap have natural padding around them, so my content was only something like 668 pixels wide (despite wkHTMLtoPDF loading the page in an 800-pixel wide browser). When I replaced this with `<div class="container-fluid">` my margins suddenly started working

Just something worth checking

Comment: I think this is a useful answer. Just a note for future readers that the class mentioned in this answer is Bootstrap specific, and so mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

use wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6, wkhtmltopdf 0.10.0 rc2 not compatible

Comment: Not compatible with what? Please note that there are already answers, and answers that are upvoted, indicating others have found them helpful.